# How to find the inverse from this?

Tags: matrices

One problem I stumbled upon sounds like this:

$$ P=\left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     0&1&0 \\
     1&0&0 \\
     0&0&1
  \end{array} \right]
$$

B=[A|P]

If

$$ B=\left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1&0&0&x_1&x_2&x_3 \\
     0&1&0&x_4&x_5&x_6 \\
     0&0&1&x_7&x_8&x_9
  \end{array} \right]
$$

1. What is $A^{-1}$?
2. What do the last three columns of B represent?

Thank you.

Comment: What does $\left[\,A\vert P\,\right]$ mean?

Comment: Hint: look at $\mathbf P^\top\mathbf P$.

Comment: @7530: it's a block matrix.

Comment: I recently wrote up [something related to this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83703/how-to-solve-3-eq-system-by-the-inverse-matrix-when-the-matrix-gets-a-zero-on-t/85130#85130). Hope it helps.

Comment: @J.M. I must still be missing something... if B is just a block matrix then clearly $A=I$, the right columns are the columns of $P$ and there's nothing to do in this problem?

Comment: @7530: Hmm. I suspect that row reduction was done in the second instance of $B$, but OP neglected to indicate this.

Comment: @J.M. Ahhh I see. Yes that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: I'm sorry for this. The x's stand there for some numbers which I can't remember. There were some given numbers, different than only 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $P$ is an elementary matrix. Moreover:

1) Multiplication of $A$ by $P$ on the right interchanges columns one and two of $A$.

2) Multiplication of $A$ by $P$ on the left interchanges rows one and two of $A$.

3) $P^{-1}=P$.

Now suppose $B=[\,A|P\,]$ and that

$B$ is similar to $  \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1&0&0&x_1&x_2&x_3 \\
     0&1&0&x_4&x_5&x_6 \\
     0&0&1&x_7&x_8&x_9
  \end{array} \right] $  (I assume this is what the OP meant).

Then $[AP|PP]=[\,AP\,|I\,\,]$ is similar to

$  \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     0&1&0&x_2&x_1&x_3 \\
     1&0&0&x_5&x_4&x_6 \\
     0&0&1&x_8&x_7&x_9
  \end{array} \right]\sim
 \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1&0&0&x_5&x_4&x_6 \\
     0&1&0&x_2&x_1&x_3 \\
     0&0&1&x_8&x_7&x_9
  \end{array} \right]
 $

So $(AP)^{-1} =\left[ \matrix{
     x_5&x_4&x_6 \\
     x_2&x_1&x_3 \\
   x_8&x_7&x_9
 }\right]$.

Now $PA^{-1}=P^{-1}A^{-1}=(AP)^{-1}$; whence $A^{-1}=P(AP)^{-1}$, so:
$$
A^{-1} =P\left[ \matrix{
      x_5&x_4&x_6 \\
     x_2&x_1&x_3 \\
   x_8&x_7&x_9
 }\right]=  \left[ \matrix{
   x_2&x_1&x_3 \\
      x_5&x_4&x_6 \\
  
   x_8&x_7&x_9
 }\right].
$$

The last three columns of $B$ give the matrix $P$, which is described above.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you are given that $[A|P]\sim[I|C]$, i.e. $[I|C]$ can be obtained from $[A|P]$ using row operations.
The matrices $P$ and $C$ are given and you want to know what $A^{-1}$ is.

Performing a row operation is the same thing as multiplying both matrices by an elementary matrix from the left - see e.g. this question: [elementary matrices and row operations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69393/elementary-matrices-and-row-operations).

So basically you know that
$$[I|C]=[EA|EP]$$ 
where $E=E_n E_{n-1}\dots E_1$ is the product of the elementary matrices used in the row reduction.

Thus you know that $EA=I$, which means $E=A^{-1}$, i.e. $E$ is the matrix you want to get.

So you are asked to find $E$ such that $EP=C$. This means that $E=CP^{-1}$.

For the given matrix $P$ it's even simpler. You can notice that $PP=I$. This means that $P^{-1}=P$ and $E=CP$.